# I have a selection box with 5 option values. I want to repeat a table row based on the value I select from it

Tags: jquery, html

This is my select box code:

```
<select class="form-control">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

This is the table row I want to repeat:

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="" placeholder="Name"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="" placeholder="Email"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="" placeholder="Mobile No."></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your Jquery like this - 
Give an Id to your select box -

```
<select id="times" class="form-control">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

I am assuming that your table has a class of tableData.
Now write Jquery -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     var row = '<tr>';
         row = row + '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="" placeholder="Name"></td>';
         row = row + '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="" placeholder="Email"></td>';
         row = row + '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="" placeholder="Mobile No."></td>';
         row = row + '</tr>';
     $("#times").change(function(){
        $(".tableData").html('');
        $(".tableData").html(row);
        var getTimes = $(this).val();
        for(var i = 0; i < getTimes; i++){
            $(".tableData").append(row);
        }
     });
});
```

Comment: It works but if I select two its shows two rows but again if i select one one get added to these two rows. I want it to get replaced by one row. I only want to display the no. of rows that I select from the box.

Comment: I have updated the code. Now it will reset the html data inside the table every time you make a change @Akhilraj

Comment: But I want to display a row by default and then change upon slection... Ignore this... It works.. Thank you

Comment: Updated again  try if you need.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.form-control').change(function() {
  $('#table').find('tr:not(:nth-child(1))').remove()
  var value = $("option:selected", this).val();

  for (var i = 0; i < value; i++) {
    $('#table').append($('#table').find('tr:nth-child(1)').clone())
  }



})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control">
<option></option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="" placeholder="Name"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="" placeholder="Email"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="" placeholder="Mobile No."></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

1. Use change event of the select to clone the first TR
2. Depending on the value of option selected use it as number of iteration to append the tr

Answer (score 0):

I think this code helps you to solve your problem.
https://jsfiddle.net/karanmehta786/orecu2ky/

Change that section of for loop

```
 for (var i = 0; i < value; i++) {
$('#table').append($('#table').find('tr:nth-child(1)').clone())}
```